# How to create specific graph with MRTG

Tags: graph, draw, mrtg

I have just set up MRTG server. Now It can get SNMP info from our router.in the first we create config file by using cfgmaker, everything is ok. We can get graph well. We have edit something on our config file about maxbytes or something like that. Afterthat we have just bring up new interface on our router. When we run cfgmaker again, it will create config file with new interface, but all thing that we edited, has been reset to default.

How can I create config file for specific interface that I can point out it. I don't want it run again for old interface that I create in previous. Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cfgmaker` utility will always generate a complete new configuration file.  It will not modify an existing file.

If you have customisations that you need to be done, you have a few options.

Firstly, you could just cut and paste the new interface stanza from the newly generated configuration file into the old one.

Secondly, you could use the various options to `cfgmaker` to customise global options, or how the interfaces are filtered, labelled and identified; whether this is enough will depend on what your customisations are.

Thirdly, you could use a host template or interface template to fully customise the output, adding targets or options.  Various templates are available at http://cfgmaker.steveshipway.org/ for download.  This will require a little Perl coding knowledge.